# Dynamically loading options for a row

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, eureka-forms

This is a question related to the Swift open source project called [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) and I'm posting this question here on SO since they monitor their tag here.

Okay so I create a form in the `viewDidLoad` method of a view controller. At the same time I make a http call to an API to get a list of data (jobs). This call is asynchronous. I want to display these jobs as option values in a `PushRow`.

Since this API call is asynchronous, by the time this data is received, the form is already set up. I have a class level array setup to be populated with the list of jobs from the http call. That same array is assigned to that row's `options` property. I assign the values to the array when I receive the data. But then when I go and tap on the `PushRow`, it's empty.

```
class CreateEventViewController: FormViewController {

    private var jobs = [Job]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupForm()

        api.getJobs(.LeadCreated) { jobs, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if let jobs = jobs {
                self.jobs = jobs
            }
        }
    }

    private func setupForm() {
        form
            +++ Section()
            <<< PushRow<String>("Jobs") {
                $0.title = "Choose Job"
                $0.options = jobs.map { $0.description }
                $0.selectorTitle = "Choose..."
            }.onPresent { from, to in
                to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: from, action: #selector(CreateEventViewController.multipleSelectorDone(_:)))
            }
    }

}
```

Is there some sort of a way to refresh or reload the data for a specific row or the form as a whole?

---

**Update 1**

As per Kevin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36412216/1077789) below, I modified my code as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    api.getJobs(.LeadCreated) { jobs, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let jobs = jobs {
            self.jobs = jobs

            if let jobsRow = self.form.rowByTag("Jobs") {
                jobsRow.updateCell()
            }
        }
    }

    setupForm()
}
```

But for some reason, it's still not working. The options are empty. The cell is correctly picked up via the tag, I checked. Anyway failing this, I also tried `tableView.reloadData()` as well but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it! You had to add the `.cellUpdate {...}` closure to the row and inside it assign the values to the `options` property. Like so,

```
<<< PushRow<String>("Jobs") {
    $0.title = "Choose Job"
    $0.options = jobs.map { $0.description }
    $0.selectorTitle = "Choose..."
}
.cellUpdate { cell, row in
    row.options = self.jobs.map { $0.description }
}
```

Comment: Great I had the same problem. Is it possible to pass an object so when you select the row you can get all properties of your object? Any clue?

Comment: Yes, you can. Make your object conform to the Equatable protocol and then you can pass your own objects to the row. Like PushRow<Job>("Jobs")

Comment: Is there any sample code to see. Appreciate so much

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the README in the FAQ section there is a reference to reloading

> ### How to set the form values using a dictionary
>
> ...
>   If the form was
>   already displayed we have to reload the visible rows either by
>   reloading the table view `tableView.reloadData()` or invoking
>   `updateCell()` to each visible row.

However, I don't even think that's necessary. Just call `setupForm()` after you update `self.jobs`.

You can see from the `FormViewController` source code that when `form` is set, the tableview is reloaded.

```
public var form : Form {
    get { return _form }
    set {
        _form.delegate = nil
        tableView?.endEditing(false)
        _form = newValue
        _form.delegate = self
        if isViewLoaded() && tableView?.window != nil {
            tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I totally overlooked that in the README. Unfortunately I'm still facing the same issue. I updated my question.

Comment: Did you try adding `setupForm()` after you do `self.jobs = jobs`? The form is generated based on `self.jobs` so it needs to be updated before the tableview is updated.